# function php (mail) doesn't work. Learn Head First

Tags: php

This is my first topic in our service.

I read book Head First PHP and MySql. I have some problem in generate e-mail.

Server in xampp or diffrent servers give me error:
Undefined variable: mail
Function name must be a string

I configured XAMPP using the following instruction :
https://system66.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html

Can you help me :)? 
Thanks for response.

Below is a code:

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST ['firstname']. ' ' . $_POST ['lastname'];
    $how_many = $_POST ['howmany'];
    $when_it_happened = $_POST ['whenithappened'];
    $how_long = $_POST ['howlong'];
    $alien_description = $_POST ['aliendescription'];
    $fang_spotted = $_POST ['fangspotted'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $other = $_POST ['other'];
    $what_they_did = $_POST ['whattheydid'];

    // Sending e-mail

    $to = 'testowymail@test.pl';
    $subject = 'Porwanie przez kosmitow';
    $msg = "$name . 'porwano mnie : $when_it_happened  i nie było mnie przez :  $how_long.\n" .
        "liczba kosmitów : $how_many\n" . 
        "Opis kosmitów : $alien_description\n" .
        "Działania kosmitów: $what_they_did\n" .
        "Czy widziano kła? $fang_spotted \n".
        "Inne komentarze $other";

    $mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);




    echo 'Dziękujemy za przesłanie formularza. <br/><br/>';
    echo "Masz na imię i nazwisko: " . $name . "<br/>";
    echo 'Porwano Cię: ' . $when_it_happened . '<br/>';
    echo 'I nie było Cię przez: ' . $how_long . '<br/>';
    echo 'Opis kosmitów: ' . $alien_description . '<br/>';
    echo 'Czy widziano Kła? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adres e-mail: ' . $email . '<br/>';
    echo "Co z toba robili? " . $what_they_did . "<br/>";
    echo 'Dodatkowy opis kosmitów: ' . $other . '<br/><br/>';   
?>
```

Comment: It's `mail(..)`, not `$mail(..)` - like the error says, it's not a variable, it's a function.

Comment: Read the message? Undefined variable `$mail`? Start debugging by reading the first error/warning you see.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);
```

Should be

```
  mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);
```

Remove the $

Comment: Thanks for help! I'm remove $ to code. Code generate correct, but I'dont get mail :(

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If there are no PHP errors, then I would guess the server is not configured to send email correctly.